# Union of infinite subfields of the complex plane

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Is the union of all subfields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ for $n \geq 1$ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$?

The previous section of the question asked me to prove that the union of an infinite number of subfields $K_n$ with $K_n \subseteq K_{n+1}$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

I am struggling to make any ground as I'm not sure how to begin answering the question.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. For your specific question: have you tried to show $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt n)$ for some $n≥1$, for instance?

Comment: Try to look for Elements in small unions like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2))\cup\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(3))$. Then try to express them as $\sqrt(n)$ for some n, or prove that such an n doesn't exist.

Comment: I have no idea how to even begin answering this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the fields $K_n = \Bbb Q(\sqrt n)$ are not totally ordered for the inclusion.

Let $A$ to be the union of the $K_n$, for $n≥1$. Consider $x=\sqrt 2 \in A$ and $y = \sqrt 3 \in A$. If $A$ was a subfield of the complex numbers, then you should have $x+y \in A$. Is this the case?

> If it was the case, then $x+y \in K_n = \Bbb Q(\sqrt n)$ for some $n≥1$. Then we could write $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 = a+b\sqrt n$ for some rational numbers $a,b$. Squaring both sides yields $5 + 2 \sqrt 6 = a^2+nb^2+2ab\sqrt n$... can you continue from there?

Comment: So does this mean that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 6)$? How does this help?

Comment: Then you could find non-zero rational numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha^2+6\beta^2 = 5$ and $2\alpha \beta = 6$. Is this possible?

Comment: I see, so the fact that this is impossible is sufficient to prove that the union is not a subfield? I also assume that if this were possible that would not be sufficient to prove that it _is_ a subfield.

Comment: You are correct. It is _not_ a subfield. But if it was, our argument wouldn't be sufficient.